# How do I run tests on multiple browsers in lambdatest?

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have a lambdatest and testcafe setup, lambdatest account has a single parallel run. 
As far as I understand, testcafe doesn't support queuing of tests. 
So my question is how do I manage to run tests on different browser/OS combination on lambdatest(one after the other without queuing).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create several runners for each browser and run them in series. You can find an example in the following thread on GitHub:
https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/2495#issuecomment-421090352

Comment: Thanks for the response, I was able to successfully run tests on multiple browsers.

Answer (score 1):

As Dmitry stated, you can create several runners for each browser and run them in series.

Here is an example code to run parallel testing over LambdaTest [Selenium Grid](https://www.lambdatest.com/selenium-automation?utm_source=StackOverflow&utm_medium=Ans&utm_campaign=LT-Thread&utm_term=HP-19-06-2020) through custom testcafe runner.

```js
const browsers = [
  ['lambdatest:Chrome@74.0:Windows 10"', 'lambdatest:Chrome@75.0:Windows 10'],
  ['lambdatest:Chrome@76.0:Windows 8', 'lambdatest:Chrome@77.0:Windows 8'],
];
const runTest = async browser => {
  console.log('starting tests');
  await createTestCafe('localhost', 1337, 1338)
    .then(tc => {
      testcafe = tc;
      const runner = testcafe.createRunner();
      return runner
        .src(['web-tests/*.ts'])
        .browsers(browser)
        .run();
    })
    .then(async failedCount => {
      console.log('Tests failed: ' + failedCount);
      await testcafe.close();
      return;
    });
}
const runAllBrowsers = async () => {
  for (const browser of browsers) {
    await runTest(browser);
  }
}
```

For more information, refer to [GitHub repository of LambdaTest & Testcafe](https://github.com/LambdaTest/testcafe-sample). Cheers!

Comment: While it is perfectly fine to occasionally refer to your own web site, please remember that you *must* disclose your affiliation in your answers. Please see: [*How to not be a spammer*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion)